# Multiple QWidgets in the central widget

Tags: qt

I'm just starting out with Qt and I'm trying to write an app with an interface, written by hand, not with Qt Designer, that looks like this

[image]

but I can't figure out how to add more than one widget to the central widget, and I can't find any documentation or examples that I could use. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Shouldn't `centralWidget()->addWidget(button1)` and `centralWidget()->addWidget(button2)` do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest building your desired interface using QtDesigner and examining the code it generates. You don't have to use QtDesigner in your application, but this will help you to self-educate on how to properly add items, use layout management, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked out fine. I'll do that in the future.